# Way to store big custom order id in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am thinking of making an order id like **31012090134**

In which 1st digit `3` represents year's last digit i.e. 2013

Next 2 digit `10` represents month i.e. October

Next 2 digit `12` represents date of month

Next 2 digit `09` represents Hour of day i.e. 9 in the morning

And rest of 4 digits are just incremental number in that particular hour.

I am using MySQL as DB engine but I am not sure what is the perfect way of storing this into DB by which it could be retrieved swiftly when required. I don't want customer to be waiting for 3-4 seconds waiting for the loading of order tracking page just because system was busy finding a particular Order Id from DB. Considering the size of `INT` datatype in mysql I don't think that I can use that. And searching through `Varchar` does't seems right. `Bigint` is an option that is looking fine, but now sure for it.

What I was thinking of is to split it into multiple tables according to their values that they represent. But as I am also using `order_creation_time` as a column in same table, I could use that also to narrow down to a specific date and make a select query on last 4 digits.

Could you suggest a good way of doing this? Or is there any fault with this order number naming pattern?

Comment: this is not a good approach to say the least. why don't you use the native timestamp types?

Comment: @SamD I am also using `datetime` for storing creation date. It is just Order Id that I am going to give to the customer.

Comment: what's wrong with the regular int incrementating in mysql?

Comment: @SamD there is nothing wrong with that, I am using that also internally for orders but this order Id is just for not exposing my internal orders count to my customers.

Comment: you can make field for customer_order_id and make it a secret multiple of order_id

Comment: The biggest trouble will be incrementing and avoiding duplicates.

Comment: You should've mentioned earlier that it will only be used for display. I think that it now is a trivial question as most answers are based upon having other ideas in mind.

Comment: @MarcusAdams How duplicates will occur for this series, only possible case can occur when year repeats, e.g, for 2023 repetition most probably will happen. But to be practical who knows where the world will be after 10 years :)

Comment: @skiwi Ya, I should have mentioned it before, by looking at all the answers, I am also getting the same feeling. I thought it was very intuitive why a person make a custom order id.

Comment: @Abhi, you must have some scheme to increment/avoid duplicating the incremental portion of the ID, though you haven't explained your plan.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want this approach, then you could do the following:

- Use a `DATETIME` field to hold the day and hour fields, remember to always set the minutes and seconds to zero.
- Use an `INT` field to store the daily order id.

Then in order to ensure that you always have unique data, you will need to:

- Have an `UNIQUE` key on the DATETIME and INT fields together. Like: `UNIQUE_KEY(datetimeField, intField)`

This does mean, however, that your application has to keep track of the logic needed to get an unique daily order id. This also be done in MySQL `PROCEDUREs`, `FUNCTION`s or `TRIGGER`s if you wish to do so.

**UPDATE:**
I have read in your comments that it seems like only want to show this custom order id to your users and use it nowhere else in the application logic.

If that is the case, then the most logical options are:

- `BIGINT`: The advantage would be that you can take advantage of an index.
- `VARCHAR`: The advantage would be that you need not to worry about the size of an `BIGINT`.

Comment: `Use an INT field to store the daily order id.` I think the range of INT will not allow OP to store the ID which is his primary concern

Comment: @RahulTripathi It will in this case, because I broke his requirement down into two pieces. So all he needs to store into the `INT` field now is the daily order id, which from his indications can have a maximum of 4 digits. And `INT` fields would still do well with a reasonbly high number of order id's.

Comment: OK I got that. Looks neat. But what is the harm in taking it as BIGINT?

Comment: @RahulTripathi There's no harm on using `BIGINT`. Both approaches have their advantages and disadvantages. One of the advantages of `BIGINT` is that it only has one column, one of the advantages of my approach is that you can easily search on the day and hour.

Comment: Yes, you got my point. Actually I was thinking the same that by using BIGINT OP only has to create a single column instead of the approach which you took. :)

Comment: If it's for display only, then make it a calculated field and store the values in separate fields as described here. You can actually use autoincrement on a compound index with MyISAM and BDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 2):

The `varchar` for sure, this is why:

- A `bigint` is better for searching, and in this case, for memory usage
- `varchar` is worse for searching, but the good thing is that will allow you to change reference strategy (i.e include some letters) in the future, without having to change your database. And its always good to be ready to the future.

For the problem of the search performance with `varchar`, is not a real problem, since **you just need to create an index in that column**, so the MySQL server wont have to iterate through the records, **and every search is as almost fast as if it where an int**. so the cons of `varchar` are  solved and the pros are still there.

to create an index after table creation you just need this simple sql:

```
ALTER TABLE `orders` ADD INDEX (`order_id`);
```

with this, the engine will create and maintain a kind of a helper list ordered by that field, so any search is far as you find a word in a dictionary, you dont have to iterate through all the words, since you know very well where every word would be if it exists

**UPDATE**

Also, i'd use an extra `DATETIME` column, so time related searches can be done through this one. I suppose you already have one.

Comment: Big int is smaller and uses less memory than VarChar in this case. BigInt is 8 bytes, but VarChar requires at least one byte per character and is at least 11 bytes in this case. You are right that search speed between the two is negligible, except ... smaller is faster. Still, we often have a rule that if we're not doing arithmetic on it, then we don't make it integer (with autoincrement being the exception).

Comment: you are so rite! BIGINT is always 8 bytes, VARCHAR(15) is 1..16 bytes depending on value length, so BIGINT needs less memory on numbers with  7 or more digits, but more memory on small numbers  shorter than 7 digits. thanks for pointing it! I updated the post removing the incorrect information!

Comment: @CarlosRobles Could you please elaborate how you mean to create an index for the `varchar` column storing order id?

Comment: @CarlosRobles You pointed out a good thing for `varchar` that this column will be able to adapt to the changes in future, but I can not see a need for any changes if this scheme could be implemented in a robust manner.
My major concern is speed to fetch a record,if i have 1 million records in my table, then  mysql server will be able to find records quickly for `varchar` or `bigint`?

Comment: you have the syntax to create an index in my updated answer. Yes, the search will be fast, based on my own experience working with big data, and also based on @Marcus Adams agreement (who has 22k reputation :) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `VARCHAR` column, that'll be fine, or a `BIGINT` if you prefer. You make no definition of "swiftly", but both of those will be pretty fast under most circumstances.

The advantage of `BIGINT` is queries like `order_id BETWEEN ? AND ?` will run faster if the table is indexed on that column.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to store this in `varchar` or a `BIGINT` column

From MYSQL DOC

> A large integer. The signed range is -9223372036854775808 to
>   9223372036854775807. The unsigned range is 0 to 18446744073709551615.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BIGINT DataType to store this size of value.  From the MySQL docs

> A large integer. The signed range is -9223372036854775808 to
>   9223372036854775807. The unsigned range is 0 to 18446744073709551615.

From a design perspective, the answer as always, is "it depends" on whether this is a good idea etc, how you want ot retrieve the data etc.  If you are required to retrieve the data based on Creation Time, then you should have a column in your database to represent the CreateTime.  Don't rely on calculating the date time based on your order Id.  This will not scale well once you have large amounts of data and need to run queries.